# how to add event in Month view using Tapku Library in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, native, ipad-mini

I want to add events for Month view using Tapku Library for iOS.

I am able to add the month view but don't know how to show events in month view.

Any help /guidance is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you see this sample https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tapku-calendar ?

Comment: Do you have any example code of what you have tried ? It helps to show what you have already tried